# Set flag when looping through input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of multiple text fields and a text area. I’m looping through the text fields and the text area and checking if there is a value. If there is not a value I set a flag that says **pass=false.** Otherwise I set **pass=true** and would like to fire a custom event if everything evaluates to true. The problem is that because one input field evaluates to true it evaluates them all to true even though two of the fields have no value in them. How would I go about doing this if I wanted it so that all fields have to be filled in but still set **pass=false** if one or two of them are filled in? Any help is greatly appreciated!

JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/YyAjp/12/

HTML:

```
<form name="headerForm">
  <label for="fname">*First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
  <br/>   

  <label for="mname">*Middle Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="text" id="mname" name="mname" />
  <br/>     

  <label for="fname">*Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
  <br/>    

  <label for="notes">*Notes</label>
  <textarea name="notes" /></textarea>

  <a href="#" id="submit">Submit</a>
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
$("#submit").on('click', function() {    
    var pass;
    $("input,textarea,select").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() === ''){
            pass = false;
            $(this).prev('label').css('color','red');
        } else { 
            pass = true;
            $(this).prev('label').css('color','black');
        }
    });
    console.log(pass);
    if(pass){ alert('trigger custom event') } else { alert('pass failed'); }
});                    
});
```

Comment: If I read this right, `pass` will always get the value of the last item in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
pass = true;
```

into

```
pass = pass && true;
```

and initialize it to `true`:

```
$("#submit").on('click', function() {    
    var pass = true;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/pgM5X/

(You might also want to use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim) on the values first.)

Comment: Wow thanks @Blazemonger your awesome! I'm kind of confused on why this didn't work initially I thought if I declare var pass it automatically assumes it's true? And I'm not entirely sure what this does **pass = pass && true;** Thanks again!

Comment: @DelmonYoung that is a logical AND comparison.  true && true = true.  true && false = false and false && false = false.

Comment: Another trick would be to use a numerical counter 'fail' and initialize it to zero. Add 1 each time a test fails, and at the end, test if 'fail' is nonzero.